# Does this proof by Shelah use any "hidden assumptions"?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, cardinal-arithmetic

Recall that the approachability ideal for $\kappa$, denoted $I[\kappa]$, consists of all sets $A\subseteq\kappa$ such that there is a sequence $\overline{a}=(a_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in\kappa}$ of bounded subsets of $\kappa$ and a club $C\subseteq\kappa$ with the property that for all $\gamma\in A\cap C$, there is $B\subseteq \gamma$ unbounded of ordertype $\operatorname{cf}(\gamma)$ such that for all $\beta\in\gamma$, $B\cap\beta\in\{a_{\alpha}\;|\;\alpha\in\gamma\}$.

A result of Shelah states that for $A\subseteq\kappa\cap\operatorname{cf}(\mu)$ stationary and $A\in I[\kappa]$, the stationarity of $A$ is preserved by $\mu^+$-closed forcing $\mathbb{P}$. The proof roughly goes as follows (using modern notation):

Fix the structure $\mathcal{A}:=(H_{\Theta},<,\overline{a},\dot{C})$, where $\dot{C}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name for a club (forced by some $p\in\mathbb{P}$) and $\overline{a}$ is a sequence witnessing $A\in I[\kappa]$ (we can assume that the club in the definition is $\kappa$ itself). Now find $\gamma$ such that $\gamma\in S$ and $Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)\cap\kappa=\gamma$ and fix $B\subseteq\gamma$ unbounded of ordertype $\mu$. Now by induction on $\delta\in\mu$, let $\beta_0=0$, $p_0=p$ and, given $(\beta_i)_{i\in\delta}$ and $(p_i)_{i\in\delta}$, let $(\beta_{\delta},p_{\delta})$ be the $<$-least pair such that $\beta_{\delta}$ is bigger than the $\delta$th element of $B$ (for this we need that the set containing the first $\delta$ elements of $B$ is in $\{a_{\alpha}\;|\;\alpha<\gamma\}$ and therefore in $Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)$), $p_{\delta}$ forces $\beta_{\delta}\in\dot{C}$ and is below $\beta_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in\delta$. In the proof it is stated that by induction, $(\beta_{\delta},p_{\delta})\in Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)$ for all $\delta\in\mu$ and therefore $\beta_{\delta}\in\gamma$ for all $\delta\in\mu$. Finally, if we let $q$ be below $p_{\delta}$ for all $\delta\in\mu$, $q$ forces that $\delta\cap\dot{C}$ is unbounded in $\delta$ (hence $\delta\in \dot{C}$) and therefore forces $\dot{C}\cap A$ to be nonempty. However, this left me with two questions:

1. Do we not need additionally to $p_i\in Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)$ for $i\in\delta$ that the sequence $(p_i)_{i\in\delta}$ is in $Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)$ (which e.g. would be possible if $\alpha^{<\mu}<\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$)? If we take $\mathbb{P}=\operatorname{Add}(\omega_1)$ in a model where $2^{\omega}=\omega_2$, then, since $|Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)|=|\gamma|$, we could not have lower bounds for all descending sequences of length $\omega$ in $Sk^{\mathcal{A}}(\gamma)$.
2. Does the fact that there are stationary subsets of $\kappa\cap\operatorname{cof}(\mu)$ lying in $I[\kappa]$ have any effect on the cardinal arithmetic "around" $\kappa$ (e.g. the assumption in my first question)?

Please let me know if this question is not appropriate for mathoverflow and i will migrate it.

Comment: I think you can define the sequence $(\beta_i,p_i)_{i < \delta}$ inductively from the sequence $B\restriction \delta$, the order $<$, and the name $\dot C$, so $(\beta_i,p_i)_{i < \delta}$ and hence $(p_i)_{i < \delta}$ is automatically in the Skolem hull. Sound ok?

Comment: Sounds good. I missed that, of course, given $B\cap\beta$, we have access to the whole sequence $(B\cap\alpha)_{\alpha\leq\beta}$. Thanks!